# Xcode 7 - prerelease: "dyld shared cache could not be mapped"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I am getting this error message in the log when I am running my project on a phone. The phone is an iPhone 5s - brand new (no other apps installed) with the latest iOS 8 release. The project have been running earlier but suddenly nothing works. And the project stills runs on other devices (iPhone 4s, 5, 6, and iPads.) - deleting the app and reinstall it is tried. Resetting the phones settings is tried.

```
dyld: dyld shared cache could not be mapped
```

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this problem out?